# Retrieve Relevance Ordered Result from Text Query on MongoDB Collection using the C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I am attempting to text query a collection and retrieve the results in the text match order. [The docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-search-with-additional-query-and-sort-expressions) explain pretty well how to do this in the shell:

```
db.articles.find(
   { status: "A", $text: { $search: "coffee cake" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { date: 1, score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

but it requires the projection of the additional `score` field from the find into the sort.

In C#, I have a function that looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> TextSearch<T>(MongoCollection<T> coll, string text) {
    var cursor = coll.Find(Query.Text(text))
        .SetSortOrder(SortBy<T>.MetaTextScore(???));
    foreach(var t in cursor) {
        // strip projected score from value
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

but I am missing how to project the "textScore" value into my results, so that I can [specify the column](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/4e4f953d-8756-5f12-e83a-fe7022adb420.htm) to `MetaTextScore` in `SetSortOrder`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this working through trial and error. The trick is that your data object needs to have a field on it already that will hold the `MetaTextScore` value. So given the interface:

```
interface ITextSearchSortable {
    double? TextMatchScore { get; set; }
}
```

the final function looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> TextSearch<T>(MongoCollection<T> coll, string text) where T:ITextSearchSortable {
    var cursor = coll.Find(Query.Text(text))
        .SetFields(Fields<T>.MetaTextScore(t => t.TextMatchScore))
        .SetSortOrder(SortBy<T>MetaTextScore(t => t.TextMatchScore));
    foreach(var t in cursor) {
        // prevent saving the value back into the database
        t.TextMatchScore = null;
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that `TextMatchScore`  can't have a `[BsonIgnore]` decoration, or there will be an exception. However, it can have a `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` decoration. So by scrubbing the value off the data object before yielding it, the data object can be saved back into the collection without putting in a garbage value.